# Make openGL lines connected

Tags: c++, opengl

Right now I'v created a polygon, then I do the same thing but with line_loop to draw the outline.  My issue right now is if I set the line thickness to high, the lines arn't connected. Their ends would need to be (linewidth) longer... is there a way to fix this?

Thanks

```
glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity ();
        glOrtho (0, 600, 600, 0, 0, 1);
        glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
......
glLineWidth(5.0);
glTranslatef(250,250,0);
glRotated(x,0,0,50.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates
    //Trapezoid
    glColor3f(255,0,0);
glVertex2f(0,0);
glVertex2f(100,0);
glVertex2f(100,100);
glVertex2f(50,50);
glVertex2f(0,100);

    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); //Begin quadrilateral coordinates

    //Trapezoid
    glColor3f(0,255,0);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(100,0);
    glVertex2f(100,100);
    glVertex2f(50,50);
    glVertex2f(0,100);

    glEnd(); //End quadrilateral coordinates
```

Comment: Could you show some code please? Its early in the morning so my mind reading skills are a bit off.

Comment: You can just use `rotated(x, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)`. Using 50 won't give you a difference,  because the axis is normalised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/949-how-to-work-around-the-iphones-anti-aliasing-limitations/) shows how to achieve rounded line caps and antialised lines using a texture trick.

Comment: Ok, thats what I thought it was, just thought maybe there was a feature for it.

Comment: Link is dead :( If you could find it again, editing more details into the answer would be hugely appreciated!